# This query takes lot of time to execute, how to optimize it?

Tags: sql, database, replace, database-performance, query-performance

I have used replace to clear up the fields. but it's taking hrs to execute.

```
select c.*  
from  
(  
select distinct a.*, b.*   
from  
(  
--Table 1  
select replace(replace(replace(replace(AGENCY_NAME,'',''),'',''),'/',''),'\\','')
as agency_name,       
LEN(replace(replace(replace(replace(AGENCY_NAME,' ',''),'-',''),'/',''),'\\',''))     
as agency_len  
from dbo.tbl_stars_agency   
where replace(replace(replace(replace(AGENCY_NAME,' ',''),'-',''),'/',''),'\\','')   
not in ('')  
) a     
inner join  
(  
--Table 2  
select replace(replace(replace(replace(RESPONDENT_NAME_PER,' ',''),'.',''),'/',''),'\\','')   
as respondent_name,  
len(replace(replace(replace(replace(RESPONDENT_NAME_PER,' ',''),'-',''),'/',''),'\\',''))   
as respondent_len  
from dbo.TBL_cacs_ecb   
where replace(replace(replace(replace(RESPONDENT_NAME_PER,' ',''),'-',''),'/',''),'\\','') not in ('')     
) b  
on substring(a.agency_name,1,15)=SUBSTRING(b.respondent_name,1,15)  
) c  
inner join   
(  
--Table 3
select replace(replace(replace(replace(NM_ENTITY,' ',''),'-',''),'/',''),'\\','')  
as nm_entity,  
LEN(replace(replace(replace(replace(NM_ENTITY,' ',''),'-',''),'/',''),'\\',''))   
as nm_entity_len  
from dbo.RMFS010_TF1NAME   
where replace(replace(replace(replace(NM_ENTITY,' ',''),'-',''),'/',''),'\\','')   
not in ('')  
) d  
on substring(c.agency_name,1,5)=substring(d.nm_entity,1,5) or 
substring(c.respondent_name,1,5)=substring(d.nm_entity,1,5)
```

I want to compare the three table based on the name field in tables. I have calculated the lengths and used substring function to match up to 15 places.

Comment: Please google re stackoverflow question markup then use code block format (click on "{}") and look at how your post appears below the edit window. Also read [ask] and [mcve]. Also read about DBMS & user query optimization.

Comment: Please format your code. At a glance, since you are doing data cleansing on the fly, adding indexes will probably not help much in this case.

Comment: Hopefully, now it's more understandable.

Comment: You should clean your data before querying it. Applying functions like this eliminates your ability to utilize indexes.

Comment: If you have the capability to alter the table, you could create some calculated persisted columns, then put indexes on those columns, then join on the indexed columns. How many rows in each table? Please edit your question and add this information

Comment: Tag the dbms used! Performance questions are usually product specific. And there are some products specific functions used too.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add calculated columns and index them:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tbl_stars_agency
ADD agency_len AS LEN(replace(replace(replace(
replace(AGENCY_NAME,' ',''),'-',''),'/',''),'\',''))
PERSISTED;
```

Now add an index:

```
CREATE INDEX MyIndex dbo.tbl_stars_agency
(agency_len);
```

Now any search in this should be much faster.

You can change this line:

```
where replace(replace(replace(
replace(AGENCY_NAME,' ',''),'-',''),'/',''),'\','')  
not in ('')
```

to this:

```
where agency_len = 0
```

Try that and if it helps we can look at doing this to other columns

PS: You need to be certain your expression is watertight and won't crash due to invalid lengths etc. otherwise it will stop you inserting and updating records